# Box collision 2D Unity, Sideways collision not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

So there is a problem with my box collision in Unity, when my character collides with a box from the top or bottom, it works just fine and gets stopped, but when it moves towards it from the left or right side it does not get stopped which is not what I want to happen. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great. (Unity 2019.2.12f1)

Box collsion of the character

[image: Box collsion of the character]

Box collsion of the platform

[image: Box collsion of the platform]

```
 public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float spelerspeed = 8.0f;
    public float top = 276.0f;
    public float bottom = -270.0f;
    public bool isgrounded = false;
    public bool iswall = false;
    public int var = 0;
    public float jumpheight = 11500f;
    public float Djumpheight = 11500f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        userinput();
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "ground")
        {
            isgrounded = true;
            var = 0;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "ground")
        {
            isgrounded = false;
            var = 1;
        }

    }void userinput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && var == 1)
        {
            Rigidbody2D rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, 0);
            rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            var = 2;

          gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, Djumpheight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isgrounded == true)
        {
            var = 1;
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpheight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if (transform.localPosition.x >= top)
        {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-269, -83,0);
        }
        if (transform.localPosition.x <= bottom)
        {
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(275, -83, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)|| Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == false) 
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
            }

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)&& Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

       Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
       transform.localPosition += move * spelerspeed * Time.deltaTime;


    }

}
```

Comment: just another question/sidenote: why if in `Start` you already assign `rigidbody` later in `userInput` you do it again oce in `rb2d` and once directly in `gameObject.GetComponent ...` .. simply everywhere use `rigidbody` which would be much more efficient ;)

Comment: there is no code to do anything if the collision wasnt with ground ...

Comment: also a field/variable name `var` is not good ... `var` is a keyword. There is nothing in `userInput` which handles a `var == 0` case differently

Comment: getting into bad habbits when learning is the worst thing to do, breaking a long standing habbit is harder than not doing it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, had to change the way my Rigidbody moves:

I changed:

```
Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
transform.localPosition += move * spelerspeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Into:

```
public float runSpeed = 40f;
horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")* Time.deltaTime
Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(horizontalMove * runSpeed; * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);
```